# ASP.NET MVC3: Razor GetHTML Table custom layout

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, checkbox

Im manually Creating the table using the built in razor GETHtml Function.

```
@table.GetHtml(
    columns: table.Columns(
        table.Column("Account"),
        table.Column("Due"),
        table.Column("Topic"),
        table.Column("Type"),
        table.Column("Completed?", format:  @<input id="Complete" name="Complete" type="checkbox" onclick="/Tasks/Complete?ID=700" />)
        )
)
```

What I want is a way of clicking a checkbox, or button to activate the controller. it is not accepting Dynamic checkbox. Nor does the html checkbox do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Have a working solution without using forms, the column would be set using the following code:

```
table.Column("Completed?", format: @<input type="checkbox" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Complete", "Tasks", new { TaskID = item.TaskID })'" />
```

I think its possible that having the name property was causing it to post it as a parameter, rather than treat it as a submit.
Otherwise it must ahve been the onclick event. Ive used location.href, then set it using razor syntax, and included the id as a property.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of ways to go about performing a post to your desired controller. Wrap your table with the form you would like to submit or add a few AJAX handlers to post the data you desire. A simple form could be accomplished like:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm<SomeController>(x=> x.SomeAction())
{

@table.GetHtml(
    columns: table.Columns(
        table.Column("Account"),
        table.Column("Due"),
        table.Column("Topic"),
        table.Column("Type"),
        table.Column("Completed?", format:  @<input id="Complete" name="Complete" type="submit" " />)
        )
)

}
```

Comment: In the end, I added a new whole new form in the format section. Which does what I want. Still looking into a oneline solution where by forms may not have to be used. Didnt quite get your `(x=> x.SomeAction())`, nor understand where ID gets set.